# PHP Fails to Populate CSV File

Tags: php, sql, parsing, csv

so I am currently having an issue with my code where the csv file I am trying to alter is not populated with the data from my SQL database. The csv file is being altered in someway because everytime I run my submit button the csv file updates concurrently with the latest submission. As a result I suspect that my issues have something to do with the way I am communicating with my sql database or the way that data is being parsed to the csv file. I have my code linked below. Thank you for your time and looking. NOTE I am not receiving any sort of errors.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      $db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
        $db->connect();

      $filename = 'uploads/testfile.csv';

      $fp = fopen($filename,"w");

      $db -> query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Response");
  $q = $db;
      $result = mysql_query($q) or die ('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
      $num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator = "\n";

        echo $seperator;

        fputs($fp,$seperator);

        mysql_data_seek($q,0);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$value);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator = "\n";
        fputs($fp,$seperator);
        }


        fclose($fp);
  }

?>
```

New code:

```
$conn = get_db_connection('swcrc');
      $conn->connect();

      $sql = query("SELECT [request_ID], [user_ID], [complete], [comment], [response_date],                                    [animalClass],[animalCommon], [bioSurveyStatus]  FROM dbo.Response");
      $results = $conn->query($sql);
      $filename = 'uploads/testfile.csv';

      $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+'); 
      fputcsv($handle, array('request_ID','user_ID','complete','comment','response_date','animalClass',
                             'animalCommon','bioSurveyStatus')); 

      foreach($result as $row)
      {
          fputcsv($handle, array($row['request_ID'], $row['user_ID'],$row['complete'],$row['comment'],
                                      $row['response_date'],$row['animalClass'],$row['animalCommon'],
                                      $row['bioSurveyStatus']));
      }
      fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Why can't you use PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: I didnt even know that existed. That seems very useful, do you know how I would meld it into the code that I have written.

Comment: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { fputcsv($fp, $row); }`

Comment: And your problem is that you're fetching the row from `$q` rather than from `$result`

Comment: I just re-wrote my code, I'm going to post the new code, this time it's not modifying the csv file at all, but it is using the fputcsv function.

Comment: @MarkBaker - Hey Mark so here is my updated code, however, now it is not editing the csv file when I hit submit. Thank you!

Comment: If it's still not writing the file, check for errors on opening the file, permissions or whatever

Comment: If it's not even writing the header line, then either there's a fatal error earlier in your code, or the file can't be opened